# Control volume of one channel in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer, volume

I have an really simple audio player with AVAudioPlayer with (at this point) one song.
It is simple to control the volume of both channels (left and right) at the same time.

But is it possible to control only the left channel or only the right channel?

In this way I can set the left speaker a little louder then the right or vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [AVAudioPlayer reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/avfoundation/reference/avaudioplayerclassreference/Chapters/Reference.html) should be consulted to answer this question.

You can see from the interface that you can't control the left/right channel directly, but you can set the pan from -1 (full left) to 1 (full right). Perhaps this will achieve what you are looking for?

Using core audio will be much more difficult, but it should be able to handle this. Another possibility using AVAudioPlayer is to split the sound into its separate channels and to play them separately. Then, you can set the volume separately. There is an example in the documentation of how to ensure that two sounds play at exactly the same time. (And, you'll want to set the pan for each sound separately so that each sound plays correctly.)

A less efficient method is two play two copies of the .mp3 at once. (Caveat: I haven't tested this code.)

```
// assumes you have url for the file you want to play
AVAudioPlayer *first = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:myUrl error:nil];
AVAudioPlayer *second = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:myUrl error:nil];

first.pan = -1; // only play on left channel
second.pan = 1; // only play on right channel

first.volume = 0.6;
second.volume = 1.0;

NSTimeInterval shortStartDelay = 0.01;
NSTimeInterval now = player.deviceCurrentTime;

[first  playAtTime: now + shortStartDelay];
[second playAtTime: now + shortStartDelay];
```

Comment: I found that too, but the result was a little weird. Is there maybe another class of framework I can use to make a new player with more options(including this one)?

Comment: Core audio should handle this, but I'd recommend splitting your audio file into the left/right channels and playing the two channels separately. This will give you the control you want. (Updated my answer above to suggest this.)

Comment: The problem with this is that I have to do that before. I want (if possible of course) to let the user pick an song from their own library. And with that song I want to control the volume of each channel separately. Is that possible?

Comment: It's possible - I'm just trying to find the easiest way for you to implement it. (Core audio will be significant effort.) What if you play two copies of the song at once, but only play the left channel for one and the right for the other. Then, again, you can set the volume separately.

Comment: That could be an good idea. Is that possible with Core Audio?

Comment: Try it with the AVAudioPlayer (I haven't this myself). It is possible just with that API, although there may be limitations on the number of mp3 files that can be played simultaneously.

Comment: Ok, but then I need to load two exactly the same streams one for the left and one for the right. But how do I do that with left and right within the .mp3 (for example). For example if I want to load the stream for the left channel from the .mp3 I have to turn off the right channel within the .mp3 and load it in the left channel. Is that even possible? (I hope it is clear enough ;) )

Comment: Thanks, great idea. You think this is efficient enough to play? Are there more options? So I can test some more thinks what could be the best option?